# Definir porta automaticamente docker

Tags: virtualhost, docker

Estou utilizando docker para desenvolver minhas aplicações web, mas percebi que preciso rodar vários projetos ao mesmo tempo em minha máquina. Como esses projetos necessitam basicamente dos mesmos containers, que são o apache e o mysql, sempre que inicio algum projeto em minha máquina, preciso ficar alterando a porta do host. Existe alguma forma de eu conseguir definir automaticamente uma porta para o container que desejo criar? Por exemplo, se a porta 80 já estiver sendo ocupada pelo apache de outra aplicação, ele automaticamente aloca outra porta para a aplicação a ser iniciada.

Também gostaria de saber se existe como eu configurar a url da aplicação. por exemplo, atualmente eu acesso um projeto meu pelo link: localhost:3000. Existe como eu digitar no meu navegador meuprojeto.com.br e ele direcionar para localhost:3000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o Dockerfile do seu projeto expor uma porta, basta no docker run usar `-P` em vez de `-p porta:porta` para que o docker aloque uma porta válida qualquer dinamicamente na hora de criar o container.

Quando estamos em um docker-compose, no elemento `ports`, basta definir somente uma porta `- "porta"` em vez de `- "porta:porta"` para ter o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Show @Luiz, deu certo essa parte no meu docker-compose, mas para ser possível utilizar a alocação de porta dinâmica, seria necessário configurar uma url para o container, dessa forma o docker-compose iria decobrir qual porta é usada e quando eu digitar no meu navegador, por exemplo, projetoTeste.com, ele acessaria o ip e porta do container.